# How much revenue could an 100% land value tax be able to generate for the Indian government?

Tags: taxation, nonexpert, government-spending, land

So as a Georgist (follower of Henry George), I believe most form of taxation is immoral and economically inefficient except the land value tax (not to be confused with property taxes) and other pigovian taxes. However, I'm also a pragmatic person and therefore, it may not be possible to fund an entire government through these taxes alone as most Georgists believe.

That is why I want to ask how much revenue would an 100% land value tax be able to generate for the Indian government, assuming no changes in the current levels of the government.

I do realise such a tax would be difficult to practically implement due to poor land records in India but nevertheless, I'm interested to know if it is feasible in theory.

Comment: $0, because all land becomes instantly worthless?

Comment: @user253751 The value of a site remains the same at 100% LVT. The price someone would pay to _own_ a site would be $0 at 100% LVT but the rent someone would pay to _use_ the site remains the same whether rent is paid to a private owner or the government in the form of 100% LVT.

Comment: @sba222 then who determines the value? Usually the value is the sale price.

Comment: @user253751 Please see the comments under my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, Prosper compiled a [survey](https://www.prosper.org.au/2013/12/total-resource-rents-of-australia-2/) of all economic rents and came to the conclusion that the Australian government could effectively be funded with rents alone.

This is without taking into account that abolishing taxes will further increase the value of economic rents, i.e. in the absence of taxation firms and households will have more net income to pay for economic rents (land, carbon, licences, fees) which further increases government revenues.

Mason Gaffney ([2009](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/03068290910947930/full/html)) argues that all taxes come out of rents (ATCOR). According to this a tax reduction would increase rents by at least the same amount. This would imply that a government funded with taxes could just as well be funded with rents. See my question about ATCOR [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/42504/do-all-taxes-come-out-of-rents-atcor).

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about *land value tax* **not** *tax on rents* from land. Rent is an income stream which is different from its value

Comment: The point of 100% LVT is to tax all rents from land.

Comment: but tax on value of land does not tax rents from the land. Land value $\neq$ rents

Comment: What is your definition of land value if not the PV of land rents?

Comment: 1. Literally the article you cite Gaffney (2009) makes distinction between land rents and land values, if you think the article is wrong why do you cite it? 2. the land value will have relationship with present value of future cash flows associated with owning the land but not all of them will be necessary *economic rents*. However, the value is ultimately determined by subjective valuations, but for commercial land, assuming rationality and perfect markets the previous would more or less apply.

Comment: Gaffney writes: If future _rent_ is to be heavily taxed, there will be less current _value_ and less appreciation. One might think that increments would thus be destroyed, but economic value does not disappear without a trace. It is conserved, like matter and energy. The value is rather transferred to the public. The right to levy future taxes has a
present value, too.

Comment: What else other than present or future rents does land value include in your view? Expectations about future rents may be subjective but they remain expectations about rents. In fact, taxing current rents avoids subjective land valuation being carried out by the government.

Comment: @sba222 if the tax on rent is 100% then the rent will be $0 because why bother

Comment: @user253751 The rent someone would be willing to pay for _using_ a site is independent of whether LVT is 0% or 100%. It's just a matter of who receives the rent. However, the price someone would be willing pay for _owning_ the site's future land rents will be $0 at 100% LVT since all future land rents will be taxed.

Comment: @sba222 Then it amounts to government ownership of all land, correct? I heard Singapore kinda does this and it's been tremendously helpful towards their productive use of land.

Comment: @user253751 _Economically_ it’s the same whether the land rent that a tenant pays a private land owner is taxed at 100%, or the tenant pays the land rent directly to the government as land owner. To my knowledge Singapore has a mix of both: the government sells 99-year leases which are also taxed, but not at 100%, which is why _prices_ paid for these leases are not $0.

Comment: @sba222 What happens to those who own, use, but do not rent? I think it quickly degenerates to an implied rent, which's just a tax.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev Do you mean the implication of a 100% LVT for owner-occupiers? In principle they would pay a 100% tax on imputed rent. The government could of course offer exemptions e.g. for pensioners or students, or cap LVT at a percentage of household income.

Comment: @sba222 Then that would lead to all sorts of other issues, like possibly even having _negative_  price for when the government's idea of implied rent does not equal to the owner's perceived utility (that is, unless the government is willing to always buy it at zero). Taxing an actual stream of money is easy. Taxing gets trickier if the valuation is not already performed by the participants, and trickier still if you are to arrive at as exact a number as 100%.

Comment: Unless the ambition is to tax 100% the government can assess below market value to avoid widespread contestation. If the idea is to tax 100% it is arguably easier for the government to own the land and lease it at market, like Singapore does.

Answer (score 0):

Technincally, even if it's a stylized fact that has been subject to a lot of criticism (and, to me, very righteously), the Laffer curve indicates that a 100% tax rate on land would generate zero revenue, since there would be no incentive for the owner to use productively. In that case I think that Laffer's intuition of a zero revenue on a 100% tax rate is quite correct...